# How to make Alpine OS install .run files?

Tags: linux, docker, operating-system, alpine-linux

I have a 'program-required-x64.run' file.

Does alpine OS support running these .run files. I am trying to run it through a dockerfile later, but for now am just trying to install it manually.

With the following commands I can get it working through ubuntu absolutely fine:

```
docker run -it ubuntu

apt-get update
apt-get -y install wget
apt-get -y install unzip

wget http://companysite/program-required.run.zip
unzip program-required.run.zip
chmod +x program-required.run
./program-required.run
```

However when using alpine with similar commands it makes the file executable, but does not actually run it to install the software. 
(The Commands are similar to above, just the openjdk image comes with wget and zip so does not require the install phase.)

```
docker run -it openjdk:8-alpine

wget http://companysite/program-required.run.zip
unzip program-required.run.zip
chmod +x program-required.run
./program-required.run
```

Things I have checked:

- uname -a : both are x64  (Linux 9631f09d9c87 4.9.93-linuxkit-aufs #1
  SMP Wed Jun 6 16:55:56 UTC 2018 x86_64 Linux)
- File is runnable (ls -a
  shows it with x permissions )
- Works fine installing on ubuntu, just not alpine.

Comment: For technical reasons, some programs don't work on Alpine, so you might have to use some other distribution (with the full GNU libc) as your base.  Tip: if you write this list of commands in Dockerfile syntax then you'll just need to re-run `docker build` to repeat the recipe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any specific .run extension for any Linux binaries. Most likely you are missing a library like libc, causing Linux to report that it cannot execute your command, or give you a not found error message. You can check for shared libraries with:

```
ldd /path/to/app
```

Go through each library listed and check if it exists inside your container.